# On dpi option from imsave

Tags: python, matplotlib, resolution

Consider the following MWE to generate a random image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pts = np.random.random_sample((1024, 1024))

plt.imsave('foo.png',pts, dpi=300)
```

I'm trying to understand how the `dpi` option works. According to the [matplotlib.pyplot.imsave](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html) documentation,

> `dpi : int`
>
> The DPI to store in the metadata of the file. This does not affect the resolution of the output image.

The output of the program above is a `1024x1024` image file.

What I don't understand is the fact that neither `identify -verbose foo.png` nor `exiftool foo.png` shows the image resolution.

But, opening it with ImageMagick (display) and checking the image info, I find

[image]

So, what is *the math* behind the resolution and printing size values?

How to obtain a `300dpi` resolution image?

Answer (score 1):

Image formats like png do not have a dpi defined. If you save a 1024 x 1024 pixel array via `imsave`, the image will simply be 1024 x 1024 pixel.

Imagemagick seems to ignore any metadata, so it assumes a resolution of 96 dpi. From the pixel size (1024) and the dpi (96) it then calculates the size in inches to be

```
1024 dots / 96 dots per inch  = 10.667 inch
```

That said, the question "How to obtain a 300dpi resolution image?" is not really clear. But most graphics viewers would allow to scale the image prior to printing, so it shouldn't be a problem to get a 300 dpi print on paper.

Comment: Now I see what is happening. In fact, I would like to save a `5000 x 5000` array as a `jpg` image with `300dpi` and `105mm x 105mm` (according to instructions I got from the publishing; so I don't know if it makes sense).

Comment: Ok, but as said, dpi is irrelevant for pixel images. So if you need a 5000 x 5000 pixel image out, your array needs to be resampled.

Comment: I created the array with 5000 lines and columns. I'd like to make sure that the image will be printed in good quality when resized to 105mm.

Comment: 105 mm is 4.13 inch. 5000 pixels divided by 4.13 inch results in a dpi of 1200. This is considered a high quality for standard printers (e.g. my own printer only allows for 600 dpi).

Comment: Oh, thanks. So, what do you recommend: resize the image with `convert` to 1200x1200?

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, you can set the output density by

```
convert image <processing> -density 300 newimage
```

Then to check the density you can do either

```
identify -verbose newimage

or

identify -format "%xx%y"
```

to find the density (resolution)

Comment: What should `<processing>` be?

Comment: Whatever processing you want. If you do not want to do any further processing, then just `convert image -density 300 result`. With that command you can also change formats, such as `convert image.png -density result.jpg`. If you already have an image and it has density assigned, then just use one of my `identify` commands to get the resolution/density values.